# How to list all the shell keywords?

Tags: command-line, bash

```
$ type if
if is a shell keyword
```

I don't know the other shell keywords.

Is there any command 
to list all the bash shell keywords.?

Note: `help -m` displays both shell builtins and shell keywords.

Comment: I am glad to share these two links which are related and helpful: visit [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/151118/66803) & [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/948008)

Comment: Related (for builtins instead of keywords): [How do I list all available shell builtin commands?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512918/how-do-i-list-all-available-shell-builtin-commands)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For this exists that shell builtin command called `compgen` which most certainly you did not notice it when you run `help -m`.

```
$ compgen -k
if
then
else
elif
fi
case
esac
for
select
while
until
do
done
in
function
time
{
}
!
[[
]]
coproc
```

See `help -m compgen` for more info about `compgen`.

Comment: `time` and `coproc` are implemented as keywords but they feel more like regular commands when you're writing Bash.

Answer (score 5):

Idea taken from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/63084/18887):

- In bash, to list all keywords, first run the following command in terminal:

  ```
  complete -A keyword :
  ```
- Then type at the prompter: <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Works very well for me:

```
!         {         coproc    elif      fi        if        then      while     
[[        }         do        else      for       in        time      
]]        case      done      esac      function  select    until
```