# How do I list all available shell builtin commands?

Tags: command-line, bash

We know bash supports number of  **buitin commands**  like:

```
$ type type cd help command
type is a shell builtin
cd is a shell builtin
help is a shell builtin
command is a shell builtin
```

I want to get **list of all available shell builtin commands**. How do I do that by command-line?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands

Comment: Related (for keywords instead of builtins): [How to list all the shell keywords?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445753/how-to-list-all-the-shell-keywords)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `compgen -b` from a bash shell to get a list of the shell's builtin commands.

Answer (score 22):

From the terminal type:

```
help
```

---

From `help help`:

```
Display information about builtin commands.
```

Comment: Note that `help` lists [shell keywords](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445753/how-to-list-all-the-shell-keywords) as well as shell builtins (and does not state explicitly which is which).

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively you can display with `enable` command: (Both @karel's and @steeldriver's answer works fine.)

```
enable -a | cut -d " " -f 2,3
```

If any builtin is disabled then it is shown with `-n` in out put.

Example output:

```
$ enable -a | cut -d " " -f 2,3
.
:
[
alias
bg
bind
break
builtin
caller
cd
command
compgen
complete
compopt
continue
declare
dirs
disown
echo
enable
eval
exec
exit
export
false
fc
fg
getopts
hash
help
history
jobs
kill
let
local
logout
mapfile
popd
printf
pushd
pwd
read
readarray
readonly
return
set
shift
shopt
source
suspend
test
times
trap
true
type
typeset
ulimit
umask
unalias
unset
wait
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way: `man builtins`

It displays the list of builtins at the top, then has all the details for each command below.

```
SYNOPSIS
       bash defines the following built-in commands: :, ., [, alias, bg, bind,
       break,  builtin,  case,  cd,  command,  compgen,  complete,   continue,
       declare,  dirs, disown, echo, enable, eval, exec, exit, export, fc, fg,
       getopts, hash, help, history, if, jobs, kill, let, local, logout, popd,
       printf,  pushd, pwd, read, readonly, return, set, shift, shopt, source,
       suspend, test, times, trap,  type,  typeset,  ulimit,  umask,  unalias,
       unset, until, wait, while.
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who hate forking external binaries simply for data formatting / extraction:

```
while read -r _ cmd ; do echo $cmd ; done < <(enable -a)
```

Comment: Why not simply a pipe instead of a FIFO redirection? `enable -a | while read ...`

Comment: That would also work. This is just a habit I am in so that any variable manipulation that I care to do inside the while loop is not executed inside a sub-shell. (Manipulating variables inside a sub-shell would mean that the changes are not persisted to outside the other end of the loop).

Answer (score 1):

Just type in the Terminal:

```
man bash
```

This will open the manual of bash. Scroll down you will find **SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS**. Here you can know about all the builtin commands and what they do. If you want the manual in a txt format, use this command

```
man bash > FILENAME.txt
```

Now you have the text file of bash manual.

Answer (score 0):

Well, bash is the default shell for ubuntu and the existing answers answered well.

For zshell, we can use `enable` command to list all builtins:

```
enable
```

and I get 103 builtin commands for my zshell:

```
enable | wc -l
```

Of course, we can also use `enable` to query all bash builtins:

```bsh
enable | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Already suggest in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/513361/256099)

Comment: @Pandya Can you please explain the difference between `enable` and `enable -a`? I got confused of them. I'm using zsh, and `enable` gives 103 builtin commands, while `enable -a` only gives 13 commands.

Comment: @Pandya Let me give more detail: in zsh, `enable -a | cut -d " " -f 2,3` gives 13 output, and many of them are not builtin comands, I think. e.g. `-lF` isn't, and `-q'` isn't.

Comment: oh. I will investigate it and will inform you.