# What is the package name for "ls" command?

Tags: command-line, package-management

I was reading about packages, and I wondered what are package names for commands like "ls" and "echo"? These commands were installed on every Linux machine I've worked with, and I don't know which package installs them.

```
$ sudo apt purge ls
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  E: Unable to locate package ls

$ sudo apt purge echo
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  E: Unable to locate package echo
```

And the same thing happened for lots of other commands.

Q1. Is there any package which has all these primary commands in?

Q2. Do "ls" or "echo" or ... have a package? or they are just some commands?

Q3. How can I find the package name of commands like "ls", "echo", "read" and so other?

Comment: @andrew.46 if I run `type read` I get `read is a shell builtin`.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/512918/how-do-i-list-all-available-shell-builtin-commands as well.

Comment: `apt-file search $(which ls)` outputs `coreutils: /bin/ls`.  `coreutils` is the package that provides `/bin/ls`.  Another option is `dpkg -S` if you know you have the package installed.

Comment: Thanks, but how to use with `read` command? `which read` returns "1" as exit status code.

Comment: That one is a bit tougher.  `read` is a built-in bash command.  See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/bash-builtins.7.html.
It doesn't have an executable/file because it's in the bash binary.  If `which foo` returns 1, then it's probably a built-in shell command.

Comment: I didn't see your command before. `echo` is a built-in command too, but it has an executable path `/bin/echo` @Stewart. How can I understand the difference?

Comment: @MohammadKholghi See [Why is there a /bin/echo and why would I want to use it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/960822/22949) where [muru's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/960886/22949) is about why bash and some other shells provide `echo` as a builtin and [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/960826/22949) talks about why `/bin/echo` exists. Note that the `echo` *builtin* does not have an executable path. Instead, the builtin and the external command are separate `echo` commands. They behave similarity but one is part of bash while the other is its own separate program.