# Where is the read command?

Tags: command-line

I wanted to find the `read` command, so I did:

```
$ which read
```

It returns exit status 1. Why does this happen?

Comment: `read` is a `bash` builtin, not a command on its own. Find information about `read` in `man bash` ( https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html )

Comment: As stated [in a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1154818/what-is-the-package-name-for-ls-command#comment1920844_1154818) to a previous question of you this is explained. `read` is built into bash. There is no exectuable for that command.

Comment: If you want to know syntax details about `read`, you can run the command `help read`. See the [this link for more details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991946/how-can-i-get-help-on-terminal-commands/992033#992033)

Comment: `echo` is a built-in command, but it has an executable path. @waltinator @PerlDuck

Comment: @sudodus Thanks!

Comment: `bash`'s `builtin echo` is NOT the same as `/bin/echo`, which supports ESCape sequences. @PerlDuck

Comment: @waltinator You're right that bash's `echo` builtin isn't the same as the external command `/bin/echo` that, in Ubuntu, is provided by GNU coreutils. But [both support escape sequences, and both interpret them when the `-e` option is passed and not otherwise](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sTn3g3wsct/). In general, on an arbitrary system with an arbitrary Bourne-style shell, one cannot be sure its `echo` builtin (if any!) and the external command (which is required to be present) behave in a largely similar fashion. But with bash and `/bin/echo` in Ubuntu and most other GNU/Linux systems, they do.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`read` is a shell builtin, not an external command. `which` only tells you about external commands. Assuming you're using Bash (or some other Bourne-style shell), you should typically use `type` or `command -v` instead of `which`.

```
ek@Cord:~$ type read
read is a shell builtin
```

`type` and `command` are themselves shell builtins and they know not just about external commands but also about keywords, builtins, aliases, and functions. `which` is an external command that doesn't know about those things; it only knows about external commands. Sometimes `which` doesn't turn up anything when you ask it about a command that you *can* use in your shell. Sometimes it does turn up something for a command, but it isn't the *same* thing that actually runs when you use the command in your shell.

```
ek@Cord:~$ type type command which
type is a shell builtin
command is a shell builtin
which is /usr/bin/which
```

In Bash, you can see all the current possible meanings for a command, in the order that they are tried, with `type -a`:

```
ek@Cord:~$ type -a read
read is a shell builtin
ek@Cord:~$ type -a echo
echo is a shell builtin
echo is /bin/echo
```

For more information about why you usually shouldn't use `which`, and what to use instead in various shells including Bash, see [Why not use “which”? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)

Comment: Like `cd`, `read` is always a builtin because it modifies shell internal state, so it couldn't be implemented as a separate program.

Answer (score 1):

If you know a little how UNIX and the shell work, it should be obvious from the syntax (`read var1 var2 ...`) that no external program can set a local shell variable, so `read` *must* be built into the shell.

In bash you do not just get an exit code of 1, but also a message like `which: no read in (/home/user/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games)`. That should ring a bell that if `read` is still found, it must be built-in to the shell.

Comment: easy there buddy. Your info is correct but the way you wrote it sounds a little arrogant. A lot of people don't have deep knowledge of how Linux works and to many such knowledge is not otherwise useful

Comment: @U.Windl When run from bash on Ubuntu, *`which read` prints no message*. It appears you're on a system whose `which` executable is provided by [GNU which](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/which). But `/bin/which` in Ubuntu is from [debianutils](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/debianutils). Some shells have a `which` builtin but bash doesn't. The behavior of the external command `which` varies greatly by OS, including across GNU/Linux distros. This is one of several reasons to prefer `type` or `command -v`. ([On some OSes, `which` is even a csh script.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85250))

Comment: What do you mean from "it should be obvious from the syntax (read var1 var2 ...) that no external program can set a local shell variable"? I haven't heard it before.

Comment: @Mohammad Kholghi: Try writing a command in any language you like (including a shell script) that sets a shell variable that still exists after the command ended. That's what I meant: All variable setting in a process are gone when the process exits. Maybe really think about it, then think how an external `read` program should work.

Comment: Ahaaa. I didn't know it. Thanks! @U.Windl

Comment: @520 I agree with these remarks—it’s best to communicate the why and the how and not so much make assumptions about prior knowledge, after all this is a Q&A site for people who are often trying to learn new things. What you have touched on in this answer is interesting and it would be much more helpful with some extra detail and with less passive aggression